# MATLAB: fast hash of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, hash

I'm using DataHash (https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash) to compute a sha1 hash of a matrix with 1500 rows and 700000 columns.

This operation takes around 16 seconds which makes a rather huge amount of the algorithm in case the result is cached. I use the hash to save the result of a long running operation which has the matrix as an input.

Anyone has an idea how to compute a faster hash? It would also be ok to just reduce the matrix by some fast operation. Hashing a vector would be faster, but since the matrix is rather huge i'm not sure how to achive a good smaller replacement as the hash input.

Answer (score 5):

I think that using the underlying Java framework, you could be able to achieve the same result with a good performance improvement:

```
% Your 1500-by-700000 matrix...
A = [ ... ]; 

% Convert A into a byte array called B...
B = typecast(A(:),'uint8');
% Or, as suggested, using the undocumented function getByteStreamFromArray:
% B = getByteStreamFromArray(A);

% Create an instance of a Java MessageDigest with the desired algorithm:
md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-1');
md.update(B);

% Properly format the computed hash as an hexadecimal string:
hash = reshape(dec2hex(typecast(md.digest(),'uint8'))',1,[]);
```

Comment: More generally, you can use `B = getByteStreamFromArray(A)` instead of the `typecast`. That's an undocumented function that is called by `save` to convert any variable (not just an array that you can call `typecast` on) into a byte stream for serialization. Should work for anything where `A` is less than 2GB in size.